# MacBook Air 7,2 suspend does not work

Tags: release-hera, suspend, macbook

I've installed Elementary OS 5.1 on my MacBook Air 7,2.
The problem is that the "Suspend" function does not work whether selected from the menu or by closing the lid. In both cases, the computer does not go into suspend.
When the lid is closed, the Apple sign remains lit and the computer beeps every now and then, after reopening then login is shown.
When selected via Menu the the screen becomes black but immediately shows the login again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set laptop lid action in:
/etc/systemd/logind.conf

Try to set
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
to
HandleLidSwitch=suspend

then:
systemctl restart systemd-logind

Also, do you have swap:
cat /proc/swaps

Sometimes suspend options are available in bios/efi. Might have a look there.